# Functions using multiple Foreach-Object

Tags: string, function, powershell, foreach, copy

I have a part of my script that I can't get to work. The goal is, to take files from a folder, filter and organise them by an aspect of their filename, and move them to a new folder which has had new directories made for them. i.e organised by month and year based on file name. E.g. 032 Approved warranty - Croatia - Case-2019 08-1419032, goes into a directory 2019, then 08.
The next step was creating a select all function, which cycled through numbers 01-12. Which it does just fine. Now the issue is I want to cycle for each year as well between 2017-2019. Which is where i'm stuck. 
This is my code which does work but only does all months and 1 selected year:

```
function DoWork { param ([int]$Month)

$StrMonth = $Month.ToString("00")
Echo $StrMonth.ToString("00")

    $files = Get-ChildItem $destinationpath -Filter "*$group1 $StrMonth*" -Recurse 

    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
    $year = $group1.ToString()
    $month = $Month.ToString()
    $file.Name
    $year
    $StrMonth

    # Set Directory Path
    $Directory = $targetPath + "\" + $year + "\" + $StrMonth
    # Create directory if it doesn't exsist
    if (!(Test-Path $Directory))
    {
    New-Item $directory -type directory
    }

    # Move File to new location
    $file | move-Item -Destination $Directory -Force
    }
}

if ($group -eq 'Select All') {
    1..12 | ForEach-Object {DoWork($_)}
} else {
    DoWork($group)
}
```

I want it too be able to repeat this for multiple years (Select All). 
This code was suggested but doesn't work:

```
function DoWork {
    Param([int]$Month,[int]$Year)

    $StrMonth = $Month.ToString("00")
    echo $StrMonth.ToString("00")

    $StrYear = $Year.ToString
    echo $StrYearToString

    $files = Get-ChildItem $destinationpath -Filter "*$StrYear $StrMonth*" -Recurse

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $year = $Year.ToString()
        $month = $Month.ToString()
        $file.Name
        $StrYear
        $StrMonth

        # Set Directory Path
        $Directory = $targetPath + "\" + $StrYear + "\" + $StrMonth
        if (!(Test-Path $Directory)) {
            New-Item $directory -Type Directory
        }

        $file | Copy-Item -Destination $Directory -Force
    }
}

if ($group1 -eq 'Select All') {
    2017..2019 | ForEach-Object {
        $year = $_
        1..12 | ForEach-Object {DoWork($_, $year)}
    }
} elseif ($group -eq 'Select All') {
    1..12 | ForEach-Object {DoWork($_, $group1)}
} else {
    DoWork($group, $group1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that param block in your function is not correct, define param block as below:

```
Param([int]$Month,[int]$Year)
```